# Dell Latitude e6430 not turning on at all

Tags: memory, dell-latitude

I have a dell latitude e6430. It was working fine until i removed the battery. After that it just dosent wanna turn on. When i turn it on, its stays on for like 10 seconds and then it shuts down and its showing a led error message (First led:constant, second:blinking, third:blinking). It means that no ram modules we're detected. When i put ram in, it still dosent work and i dont know what to do. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure about the light sequence. A no RAM would be the battery light blinking 2 x amber then 3 x white (on the right front side indicator lights). Not 2nd light and 3rd light blinking. Only the battery light indicates the errors as seen in this chart. If the battery light (on top) is a constant blinking amber light then it means a fatal battery error which is expected with no battery installed.

To make  matters a little more confusing, the owners manual shows storage solid, power blinking, wireless blinking as no memory detected.

So to be clear which exact light/s are solid and which are blinking?